# ZFS send/receive whilst changing dataset properties

Tags: zfs, replication

**Summary**: Is a ZFS send/receive always to receive an exact replication of the sending dataset - matching dataset properties included - or is it possible to receive into a newly created dataset with different properties (recordsize, compression etc) that the receiving data (after checksum verification etc.) can then write in to.

For example, if I receive a (non-incremental) dataset whose objects were initially written with a `recordsize=128K`, and receive into a dataset newly created by `zfs receive` but that either specifies the option `-o recordsize=1M` or inherits from a parent dataset with an current value of `recordsize=1M`, will the objects in my new dataset be written with a recordsize of `1M`, or must it be that the objects are written as an exact "replica" of the receiving dataset?

```
zfs get recordsize tank/files   # returns: 128K

# Set parent of receiving dataset to 1M
zfs set recordsize=1M freezer   

# Also set at receive time    
zfs send tank/files@transfer | zfs receive -o recordsize=1M freezer/files
```

My question is essentially:

```
# Query recordsize of objects as written in freezer
???
```

I understand that checking the recordsize of the new dataset isn't itself an answer as this would just report what the dataset property is *currently* set to, it doesn't itself say anything about the recordsize for any previous writes.  I've tried to examine the objects directly with something like

```
zdb -dd freezer
```

but my zfs version (on FreeBSD 9) seems not to accept this.

`man zfs` suggests that only 'set-once' properties must match (casesensitivity, normalization, utf8only), but it's not clear to me how objects are written in the general case.  I've also checked docs/google but can't seem to get an explicit answer on this behaviour without getting into studying zfs internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no. Recordsize cannot be changed by send/receive operation. Some of the other options can, but not recordsize.